# About visual studio and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I Have Problème in visual studio community 2015 when i install tools with xamarin and the installation finish the xamarin don't exit what the probléme ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Visual Studio Community Edition 2017. It is free too.
I would also advice to download the Visual Studio Android emulator which is much better than the Android AVD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a step by step procedure for your problem on the Xamarin page.

[Click here for more informations](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/troubleshooting/missing-vs-extensions/)

---

Notice: If the link will help you, I edit my answer with the steps on the page.